# How to get distinct values values in two columns: 'borrower' and 'owner' using only "OR" keyword

Tags: sql, distinct, keyword

How do to get all distinct email value that exists in either columns or both using "OR" operator

[image]

Comment: `select distinct owner from table union select distinct borrower from table` no need for `or`

Comment: my bad perhaps my question isn't clear, is there a way to achieve it without using union?

Comment: not really, you need to append column to rowset from below and the only way is union

Comment: Why would you want to do it without using union, because that's the operator for combining data like that. If you don't explain your issue, you probably don't get correct help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
select distinct  Result from
(select browser ,owner  from emp
) s
unpivot (Result for col in (browser,owner)) as t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/1zR-iPHQ